# averaging values of rare species in ecological surveys

Tags: r, dplyr

I am doing an analysis of fish biomass from a visual survey, below is a mock data I made up.

| date | site | species | n | mass |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5/10 | x | snapper-x | 5 | 500 |
| 6/10 | x | snapper-x | 4 | 400 |
| 6/10 | x | snapper-y | 1 | 200 |
| 6/10 | x | snapper-z | 2 | 300 |
| 7/10 | x | snapper-x | 3 | 300 |
| 7/10 | x | snapper-z | 5 | 750 |

I'm trying to get the average count and biomass of each species per site using dplyr, but I'm running into trouble since rarer species do not show up in all survey attempts. The program automatically averages the biomass per the amount of time that species shows up, e.g., snapper-x: sum/3, while snapper-z: sum/2, even though I want them all to be divided by the number of surveys I have done, which is 3 (5/10. 6/10, and 7/10).

```
avg_biomass <- raw_biomass %>%
  filter(grepl('snapper', species)) %>%
  group_by(date, site, species) %>%
  summarize(n_avg=mean(n), mass_avg=mean(mass))
```

I have also tried `summarize(mass_avg=sum(mass)/n_distinct(date)` but it didn't work since the code already grouped everything by `group_by()` above that line.

Alternatively, I could try to add new rows of the rarer species with n and mass of 0s, but I'm not sure what function I should be using to achieve that.

Comment: What is your expected output given this sample data?

Comment: the `complete` function might help ...

Comment: As designed, the `summarize` function is executing the means on the **group**, which is `date, site, species`. It seems you just want `site, species` in the group, or maybe just `species`?

Comment: @r2evans I'd like to make a stacked bar graph of different sites, but if each "species type" are divided by a different denominator, then it wouldn't work as the rarer species would get bigger proportion.

Comment: @guasi you're right I removed 'date' on the group_by() function but they still divided by occurrence not by survey repetition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible tidyverse approaches: The first divides the `sum` of `n` and `mass` by the total number of survey dates; the second inserts the missing dates with zeroes:

```r
library(tidyverse)

raw_biomass <- tribble(
  ~date, ~site, ~species, ~n, ~mass,
  "5/10", "x", "snapper-x", 5, 500,
  "6/10", "x", "snapper-x", 4, 400,
  "6/10", "x", "snapper-y", 1, 200,
  "6/10", "x", "snapper-z", 2, 300,
  "7/10", "x", "snapper-x", 3, 300,
  "7/10", "x", "snapper-z", 5, 750
)

# Divide by total surveys
raw_biomass %>%
  filter(grepl("snapper", species)) %>%
  mutate(n_survey = n_distinct(date)) %>%
  group_by(site, species) %>%
  summarize(n = sum(n) / first(n_survey), mass = sum(mass) / first(n_survey))

#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#> # Groups:   site [1]
#>   site  species       n  mass
#>   <chr> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 x     snapper-x 4     400  
#> 2 x     snapper-y 0.333  66.7
#> 3 x     snapper-z 2.33  350
  
# Add missing dates
raw_biomass %>%
  filter(str_detect(species, "snapper")) %>% # Tidyverse alternative to grepl
  complete(date, nesting(site, species), fill = list(n = 0, mass = 0)) %>%
  group_by(site, species) %>%
  summarize(n = mean(n), mass = mean(mass))

#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#> # Groups:   site [1]
#>   site  species       n  mass
#>   <chr> <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 x     snapper-x 4     400  
#> 2 x     snapper-y 0.333  66.7
#> 3 x     snapper-z 2.33  350
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot. that mutate() line is what I needed. However, I have multiple sites so it only gave me a total of ALL survey replicates, while I wanted total replicates of each site. So I had to modify the code a bit: group_by(site) %>% mutate(...) %>% group_by(site, species) %>% summarize(...).

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is missing rows: if a species just does not show up in a given site on a given date, there is no row for that. You want a row with `n` and `mass` = 0. Here is a way to accomplish that.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
allSpecies <- unique(df$species)
kpi        <- c('n', 'mass')
result     <- df[, .(species=allSpecies), by=.(date, site)][, c(kpi):=0]
result[df, c(kpi):=.(i.n, i.mass), on=.(date, site, species)]
result[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=.(site, species), .SDcols=kpi]
```